# How should I model the actors in a use case diagram for a platform that allows users to both watch videos and create their own channels, like YouTube?

Tags: uml, use-case

Should I use separate actors for "Video Watcher" and "Channel Creator," or a single actor called "User" that represents all users of the system?
i have a webapp where user can participate in an event and user can also create their events and manage them i cant find an answer should i use separate actors organizer and participant even if they are the same ? am confused.
example :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actors represent **roles**, not physical persons.

So if you think your two use case **descriptions** become clearer when you describe the user in the first case as organizer, and the user in the second one as participant, and you want to make a clear distinction between those two roles, then use two different actors, even if sometimes organizer and participant can be the same human being.

Don't forget a use case diagram is not an end in itself, it is a means to an end: it should help in gathering and describing **requirements** and is usually just a graphical add-on to a textual use case description. The goal is to make the textual description as clear as you can, and the graphical elements should correspond to the description.